# What is this scrolling tabs control in Blackberry Applications?

Tags: blackberry, tabs, scroll, scrollbar

I want to create scrollable tabs in my Blackberry application.
I found a control that is used in blackberry home screen and in many other BB apps
[image]
It has many tabs (All, Favorites , ...etc.); scrolling between tabs is easy, and next & previous tabs are clear enough for the user. I also found some applications use it like this one:
[image]
What is this controller/manager which contains: Skydrive, local,...et.? 
which class is used from SDK and which SDK version is used to implement it ?
 **Do you have any idea ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PaneView](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/pane/PaneView.html) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Is there an alternative in SDK5, I see in the documentation that it's available since SDK6 ?

Comment: You'll have to write your own to work with OS versions earlier than 6

Answer (score 0):

You can use the latest Java SDK for BB 7 to build what you are looking for.  If you download the latest SDK, you will find a lot of sample codes under:

> plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack7.0.0_7.0.0.28\components\samples\com\rim\samples